# Prove that $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n$ is connected.

Tags: general-topology

Let $\{ A_n\}_{n\in\mathbb N} $ be a collection of connected subspaces of $ X $. Suppose that for all $ n \in \mathbb N $, $ A_n $ intersects $ \bigcup_ {i = n + 1} ^ {\infty} A_i $. Is $ \bigcup_ {n = 1} ^ {\infty} A_n $ connected?

If we have that for all $ n $, $ A_n $ intersects $ A_ {n + 1} $ , it is true that the union of $ A_n $ is clearly connected, it is proved by induction. But, if $ A_n $ intersects the infinite union of the $ A_i $ (from the index $ n + 1 $), is it still true that it is connected?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not necessarily: take each $A_n$ to be the singleton set $\{(-1)^n\}$, for example.

Comment: I could review my proof based on what you told me.

Clearly $ \{A_n \} _ {n \in \mathbb N} $ is not separate, therefore it is connected (the definition). We also have that $ A_n $ intersects the union. But the generalized union of the $ A_n $ gives the set $ \{- 1,1 \} $ which is separable, therefore it is not connected. It's okay?